# How to insert and return the uuid?

Tags: java, mybatis

My goal is to insert into a table

```
CREATE TABLE event_info (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  uuid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (uuid)
);
```

```
@Mapper
public class EventMapper {
  @Insert("INSERT INTO event_info (uuid) " +
          "VALUES (#{uuid})")
  @SelectKey(statement = "SELECT UUID() as uuid), resultType = String.class, keyProperty = "uuid", before = true)
  String insertReturnUuid();
}
```

```
String uuid = eventMapper.insertReturnUuid();
```

My expected result: the uuid is not null.

My actual result

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Mapper method 'com.a.mapper.EventsMapper.insertReturnUuid' has an unsupported return type: class java.lang.String
```

Comment: What is `postEvent_Info`?

Comment: @JimGarrison `postEvent_Info` is the actual method I use. I will change it to `insertReturnUuid`.

Comment: By the way, some databases offer a data type for [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit_computing) values. This makes for efficient storage of their 128-bits. [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) and [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) are two of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.char(36) is better
2.you cannot. The only solution is to perform 2 separated queries:

SELECT UUID()
INSERT INTO table1 (id, text) VALUES ($uuid, 'text')
where $uuid is the value retrieved on the 1st step